# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a site that use a Crystal-reports, so I have installed a crystal report For Visual studio 2010 to create my reports, everything works fine in local, but when I put my site in my host server, I get this error message, please see the following picture :
http://stream.tutowall.com/pic/error.png

It's true that my host server doesn't have a crystal-report, So I have installed in the same version of CR that I have in my local , but I still get the same error message.
Here is a link of a CR that I downloaded. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Fuslogvw.exe app from MS that logging the assemblies loading and provide great details about load errors.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

After you'll read the log files, you'll have more details about why the assembly couldn't be loaded

Comment: The problem is solved, The solution is that I had to install CR for Vs2010 32 bit not 64bit. thank's !

Comment: my pleasure. It's common issue. glad you found the issue.